# How to search a list for two variables in javascript

Tags: javascript

So in my list i have alot of variables I format by saying:

```
{i = 0, j = 0, walls = [ true, false, true, true], "visited"= true}
{i = 1, j = 0, walls = [ true, false, true, true], "visited"= true}
{i = 2, j = 0, walls = [ true, false, true, true], "visited"= true}
{i = 0, j = 1, walls = [ true, false, true, true], "visited"= true}
{i = 1, j = 1, walls = [ true, false, true, true], "visited"= true}
{i = 2, j = 1, walls = [ true, false, true, true], "visited"= true}
```

The problem is I need to search for the i and j when i have the two numbers that i and j need to be. For example when the i = 2 and the j = 1. then i need to find the index for that which in this case(using the example above) would be 5.

I have tried using .indexOf() but that didn't work. I have also tried using .find() but that didn't work either.

I don't use jquery.

I have not been able to find any solutions so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you have tried?

Comment: are you using jQuery?

Comment: So that is an array with an object? Personally I would change the format to make it quicker than loops. But the solution is a for loop, over the array. Check if i is equal to X and if j = Y and there you go.

Comment: Please see [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VincentWilkie/bntn9xgL/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an array with proper object you could use [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

If ES5 needed, then use [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Polyfill).

```js
var data = [{ i: 0, j: 0, walls: [true, false, true, true], visited: true }, { i: 1, j: 0, walls: [true, false, true, true], visited: true }, { i: 2, j: 0, walls: [true, false, true, true], visited: true }, { i: 0, j: 1, walls: [true, false, true, true], visited: true }, { i: 1, j: 1, walls: [true, false, true, true], visited: true }, { i: 2, j: 1, walls: [true, false, true, true], visited: true }];

function find(i, j) {
    return data.findIndex(function (a) {
        return i === a.i && j === a.j;
    });
}

console.log(find(2, 1));
```

Minimal implementation for ES5

```js
var data = [{ i: 0, j: 0, walls: [true, false, true, true], visited: true }, { i: 1, j: 0, walls: [true, false, true, true], visited: true }, { i: 2, j: 0, walls: [true, false, true, true], visited: true }, { i: 0, j: 1, walls: [true, false, true, true], visited: true }, { i: 1, j: 1, walls: [true, false, true, true], visited: true }, { i: 2, j: 1, walls: [true, false, true, true], visited: true }];

function find(i, j) {
    var result = -1;
    data.some(function (a, index) {
        if (i === a.i && j === a.j) {
            result = index;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return result;
}

console.log(find(2, 1));
```

Comment: Someone down-voted all the answers, I'm guessing because they don't like the quality of the question. Of course that's not what the votes on answers are for.

Comment: that's why the link to the polyfill.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your objects are valid, and as in a list you are storing them inside an array. Then you can use a for-loop and check the `i` and `j` properties on each iteration, if they match then return the current index `i`.

```js
var arr = [
 {i : 0, j : 0, walls : [ true, false, true, true], "visited": true},
 {i : 1, j : 0, walls : [ true, false, true, true], "visited": true},
 {i : 2, j : 0, walls : [ true, false, true, true], "visited": true},
 {i : 0, j : 1, walls : [ true, false, true, true], "visited": true},
 {i : 1, j : 1, walls : [ true, false, true, true], "visited": true},
 {i : 2, j : 1, walls : [ true, false, true, true], "visited": true}
];

function getIndex(I, J) {
  for( var i=0; i<arr.length; i++ ) 
    if(arr[i].i == I && arr[i].j == J) return i;
}

console.log(getIndex(2,1))
```